# Arrow function or lambda expression in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I want to implement arrow function in my javascript using c# .NET,Its working fine in chrome browser but it has thrown syntax error in IE browser. My code as below,

```
$(function () {

        var mapIndexed = R.addIndex(R.map);

        var result=mapIndexed((val, idx) => idx + '-' + val, ['f', 'o', 'o', 'b', 'a', 'r']);

    });
```

Comment: Because it's not supported yet -> [Browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: Have a look at [babel](https://babeljs.io/): _"Babel has support for the latest version of JavaScript through syntax transformers. These allow you to use new syntax, right now without waiting for browser support."_

Comment: I have gone through the Babel [babel](https://babeljs.io/) and solved the issues. Now its working fine.thank you very much Andreas.

Answer (score 1):

It is not supported in Internet Explorer, so you will need to use eighter polyfills or babel to compile down you arrow functions to regular functions with `this` bind. You can check out which features supported in different versions of browsers [here](https://caniuse.com/?search=arrow).